# Colorbox and ajax, send and receive data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox, bootstrap-modal

I have a website that needs to query a database, see the results in colorbox (or a bootstrap modal will work too), select data from the results, and send those selections back to the main page to populate a bootstrap text area.

Here's what I have so far.

html:  Form submit to colorbox

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" id="pairsub" class="btn-sm-primary form-control"
     data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pairFind" onclick="submitForm">Pair Find</button>
</div>
```

colorbox JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#pairsub").click(function (){
         $.post("pairfind.php",
              $("#form1").serialize(),
              function(data){
                 $.fn.colorbox({
                 html: data,
                 open: true,
                 iframe: false,
                 width: "500",
                 height: "500px",
                });
              },
             "html");
          });
      });
```

html textarea to receive selected data:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
     <textara class="form-control" name="IID" id="IID2">/textarea>
</div>
```

Submitting the form and getting the colorbox works perfectly.  Right now, the "submit" button with the colorbox results sends the information back by php echos and refreshes the mainpage.  I want to send the selected data back to the mainpage without having to refresh it.  Ideas?

Comment: Well it does not work since  `$("pairsub").click(function (){` is wrong. You are looking for an element, not an id.

Comment: Ok...  @epascareelo  just pointing out an error isn't helping...  suggesting solutions does help.

Comment: So do you not know how how to select by an id? Add the missing `#` is the start.

Comment: Ah...  I see, that was a typo.  My code does have the # in it.  I'll edit the post.  But to my topic....  getting the selected data from the colorbox results back to the textarea.

Comment: So you have some random method `onclick="submitForm"` attached, did you remove that? What is the colorbox plugin you are using?

Comment: lightbox plugin for jQuery ver. 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

So I gave up on colorbox and when with pure bootstrap.  This code works like a charm.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
       $('#formbtn').click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'pairFind.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                async:true,
          beforeSend: function () {
             $('#spin').modal('show');
             }
          success: function(data) {
             $('#pairFr .modal-body').html(data);
             $('#pairFr').modal('show');
             $('#spin').modal('hide');
             }
        });
    });  
});
```